# 'Mono.and()' cannot be called with the supplied parameters

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-webflux

I'm trying to run the sample project located [here](https://github.com/LearningByExample/KotlinReactiveMS).  However, I'm seeing a

`Error:(38, 22) Kotlin: None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied: 
public final fun and(p0: ((Subscriber<in Any!>!) -> Unit)!): Mono<Void!>! defined in reactor.core.publisher.Mono
public final fun and(p0: Publisher<*>!): Mono<Void!>! defined in reactor.core.publisher.Mono`

in `ApiHandler.kt` class in the `buildResponse` function:

```
internal class ApiHandler(val geoLocationService: GeoLocationService, val sunriseSunsetService: SunriseSunsetService,
                      val errorHandler: ErrorHandler) {

    private companion object {
        const val ADDRESS = "address"
    }

    internal fun getLocation(request: ServerRequest) =
        request.pathVariable(ADDRESS).toMono()
                .transform(this::buildResponse)
                .transform(this::serverResponse)
                .onErrorResume(errorHandler::throwableError)!!

    internal fun postLocation(request: ServerRequest) =
        request.extract<LocationRequest>()
                .map(LocationRequest::address)
                .transform(this::buildResponse)
                .transform(this::serverResponse)
                .onErrorResume(errorHandler::throwableError)!!

    internal fun buildResponse(address: Mono<String>) =
        address.transform(geoLocationService::fromAddress)
                .and(this::sunriseSunset, ::LocationResponse)

    internal fun sunriseSunset(geographicCoordinates: GeographicCoordinates) =
        geographicCoordinates.toMono().transform(sunriseSunsetService::fromGeographicCoordinates)

    internal fun serverResponse(locationResponseMono: Mono<LocationResponse>): Mono<ServerResponse> =
        locationResponseMono.flatMap { ok() withBody it }
}
```

I'm guessing that the Spring API has changed since this code was written, but I can't figure out what to change the `.and(...)` to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is linked with a Reactor Core API change in 3.1.0.

`Mono.and()` is no longer an operator that returns Tuples, but it only cares about completion signals now (`Mono<Void>`). You should replace that `and()` operator with a `zip` or `zipWith` operator, as suggested in [the Reactor release notes](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/releases/tag/v3.1.0.RELEASE).